Mysql find users whose type is only admin
I wrote this query to get the list of all the ids in user table, but when i run this I get Lost connection to MySQL server during query, as the no of rows in user table is more than 5 million
SELECT id FROM users.user 
where user_type_id=(select id from users.user_type where user_type = 'admin') 
and email_add not in  
(select email_add from users.user 
where user_type_id = (select id from users.user_type where user_type = 'normaluser'));


What version of MySQL are we talking about?  Another thing would be that the way the tables are setup, you don't want to search for a string 'admin' you want to have a user types table with 1) normal 2) admin, 3) etc ... so that you can search by number and not string for efficiency.

Do you have the column types for that table / creation schema?  I have a hunch that if the previous thing is how it is, I'm hoping at least id is an integer you are searching for and not some string?  Because you have 3 searches it has to be per 5 million rows, its going to take a minutes doing it that way.

SET GLOBAL wait_timeout = 1000;  That will give you a LONG timeout, if that times out, increase that number until you have enough to complete the transaction in time.  Every WHERE you use that doesn't have an index value like I explained in the first section will be a slow down when it searches for criteria instead of an integer value.

user_type_id = should be user_type_id IN

tried with IN also same result @Barmar

@easleyfixed still it timeout in 30 secs

The timeout I suggested was 1000 seconds, so I don't think the timeout was changed.

You really should include a [mre], so that we can see the data structures and constraints you're working with (for example, do users exist in the user table multiple times, with rows associated by email address, and is that address unique to a given user). Only with full details maw we the be able to suggest objective improvements. Please read :  Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?

Until we see the indexes to your user table, we won't be able to show or suggest a solution. All solutions that do not use indexes will have a long execution time. If you do not have suitable indexes (this happens) - it is unlikely that you can be helped.

Changing your not in to not exists should be much better, assuming email_add is indexed:
SELECT id
FROM users.user u1
WHERE user_type_id = (SELECT id FROM users.user_type WHERE user_type = 'admin') 
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM users.user u2
    WHERE u2.user_type_id = (SELECT id FROM users.user_type WHERE user_type = 'normaluser')
    AND u2.email_add = u1.email_add
);

If it's still super slow, please update your question with the DDL for your user table and the execution plan (EXPLAIN SELECT ...).

thnks but this did not work, takes time

So, please add the requested DDL and EXPLAIN to your question.

barmar solution looks good, runs in 2 secs but is missing email address in query, trying to figure out that. @user1191247

Yes, it's very quick because it is a totally different query that does not provide the requested output ;-)

Have I understood your question correctly, in that you have multiple rows with the same email_add but different user_type_id?

yes right multiple rows with same email id but different user type id @user1191247

Then, as previously requested, please add the DDL and EXPLAIN to your question. You probably need an index on user(user_type_id, email_add)

Prefer joins rather than IN (subquery)
SELECT u.id
FROM user AS u
JOIN user_type AS ut1 ON u.user_type_id = ut1.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT email_add
    FROM user AS u
    JOIN user_type AS ut ON u.user_type_id = ut.id
    WHERE ut.user_type = 'normaluser'
) AS ut2 ON u.email_add = ut2.email_add
WHERE ut1.user_type = 'admin' AND ut2.email_add IS NULL

Make sure there's an index on user.user_type_id and user.email_add.

Hi @Barmar email address check is missing, will this not impact count

Why are you comparing id in one part, and email_add in the other?

I've updated the query to use email_add when checking for normal_user.

ut2.email_add = 'normaluser' this does not look right @barmar

Yeah, clicked the wrong place when I was editing

ON u.email_address = ut2.email_address @barmar email address is only in the user table

I'm confused about why you're using email_add in the first place. You need to exclude all the administrators with the same email as a normal user?

email address is present in user table, user table has records of both the types admin and normal user and both can have the same email address, below query is correct, problem is it takes 5 mins to execute
SELECT id FROM users.user
where user_type_id=(select id from users.user_type where user_type = 'admin')
and email_add not in
(select email_add from users.user
where user_type_id = (select id from users.user_type where user_type = 'normaluser')); @barmar

I understand it's present, but why are you using it in this query? Does the user have different accounts for each role, so you need to relate the accounts by email address?

yes correct @barmar

i wrote the exact same query you provided now, its correct, but it takes the same time like 5 mins, looks like i will increase the timeout to get the result @barmar . thnks for the help

Do you have all the needed indexes?
